# Strip curly bracket from an output in PHP

Tags: php, json, php-5.3

My php code `<?php echo $art->capt; ?>` gives the following output:

```
{"path":"location\/file.png"}
```

However, I want to show only `location/file.png` as the output and remove all the junk.

How should I proceed?

Comment: so basically you have json output but you want to not have json and just output a url? Perhaps don't output the data as json in the first place.

Comment: That's not upto me. The data is coming from the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's json. you need to decode it.

```
<?php
$str = $art->$capt; //'{"path":"location\/file.png"}';
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$path = $json['path'];
echo($path);
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly how I want however, my json file is generated with this code `<?php echo $art->capt; ?>` and I can't seem to figure out how to get going with your code! Kindly help and Thank You so much :)

Comment: This returns nothing. Not even an error. I wish I could provide more too but I don't know where to start or where to end. The code `<?php echo $art->capt; ?>` however returns the data as mentioned in my question. Did you miss something? Please check your code again. Really appreciate this effort.

Comment: $art->$capt is an stdClass Object. You should be able to assign its value to a variable. Also make sure you add the $ to capt in `$art->$capt`.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is working now. Thank You so much. You saved my day :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

That is actually [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an object (or array if you pass true in the second argument of json_decode). Get the HTML output. If the HTML isn't already in a variable use output buffering.

```
ob_start();

/*html is output here*/

$json = ob_get_contents();

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$path = $json['path'];

print_r($path);
//output should be location/file.png
```